# Why my radio button is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, radio-button

I am currently learning React JS and tried to do some hands-on by myself but having some issues in creating Quiz App where, I am using radio buttons and fetching data from TRIVIA API so that I can re-use radio-button component.

But issue I am facing is that whenever I am clicking on radio buttons only one radio button is getting selected others were unchecked itself don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here's my Code Sandbox link - [Quiz App using TRIVIA API](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiz-mania-nfwr84?file=/src/components/Question.js).

Thanks in advance.

```
export default function Question(props) {
  const [correct, setCorrect] = React.useState({ answer: "" });

  function handleChange(event) {
    setCorrect((prevData) => event.target.value);   }

  return (
    <section className="">
      <legend className="quiz">{props.question}</legend>

      <div className="radio-button">
        <input
          type="radio"
          className="btn-check"
          name={props.question} // Questions - option
          value={props.correctAns} // Value of the radio button
          checked={correct.answer === props.correctAns}
          id={props.correctAns}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label className="btn choice " htmlFor={props.correctAns}>
          {props.correctAns}
        </label>

        <input
          type="radio"
          className="btn-check"
          name={props.question} // Questions - option
          value={props.wrongAns[0]} // Value of the radio button
          checked={correct.answer === props.wrongAns[0]}
          id={props.wrongAns[0]}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label className="btn choice" htmlFor={props.wrongAns[0]}>
          {props.wrongAns[0]}
        </label>

        <input
          type="radio"
          className="btn-check"
          name={props.question} // Questions - option
          value={props.wrongAns[1]} // Value of the radio button
          checked={correct.answer === props.wrongAns[1]}
          id={props.wrongAns[1]}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label className="btn choice" htmlFor={props.wrongAns[1]}>
          {props.wrongAns[1]}
        </label>

        <input
          type="radio"
          className="btn-check"
          name={props.question} // Questions - option
          value={props.wrongAns[2]} // Value of the radio button
          checked={correct.answer === props.wrongAns[2]}
          id={props.wrongAns[2]}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label className="btn choice" htmlFor={props.wrongAns[2]}>
          {props.wrongAns[2]}
        </label>
      </div>
      <hr />
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please copy & paste the minimal, reproducible part of the code into the question.

Comment: Side note: It is probably a better practice to `map` over the `<input />` tags as they are getting info from `props.wrongAns`

Answer (score 1):

In the `Question` component the `correct` state is the selected answer string literal. Update the initial `correct` state to be an empty string and use `checked={correct === props.correctAns}` in the radio input.

```
const [correct, setCorrect] = React.useState(""); // <-- string

function handleChange(event) {
  setCorrect((prevData) => event.target.value); // <-- string
}

...

<input
  type="radio"
  className="btn-check"
  name={props.question}
  value={props.correctAns} // <-- string
  checked={correct === props.correctAns} // <-- string comparison
  id={props.correctAns}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

[image: Edit why-my-radio-button-is-not-working-as-expected]

Comment: Drew Reese, Thank you :-) for helping me out.

Comment: Thanks for asking! Yes but from your answer i found another way by which i was able to replaced repeated radio buttons with li by using map function but facing another issues trying to resolve on my own, will ask if I could not able to resolve the issue .